# javascript (Vanilla) - How to prevent HTML form post after an alert is shown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have made a quiz in html with some validation, and the next step I would like to undertake is to score this quiz in javascript. My scoring system is all well and works as intended, but I'd like to prevent the form from posting to result.html IF they score 0 on the quiz. I have managed to display an alert when this happens, but upon pressing OK, the result page loads anyway. (The result page is empty for now). I've tried looking at both window.history.back, as well as preventDefault, but I can't help but to think I am not understanding syntax for one or both of these things. I'd like the alert to show, and then the user stay on the same page. I'd also like to stay within vanilla javascript, as well as avoiding inline stuff. Thanks :)

Here is my quiz form:

```
<form name="quiz" id="quiz" method="post" action="result.html">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student Details</legend>
        <p><label for="firstName">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First" maxlength="25" required="required" pattern="^[A-Za-z -]+$" title="Please use only letters/hyphens/spaces." />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last" maxlength="25" required="required" pattern="^[A-Za-z -]+$" title="Please use only letters/hyphens/spaces." /></p>
        <p><label for="studentID">Student ID: </label>
            <input type="text" name="studentID" id="studentID" placeholder="e.g. s123456789" required="required" pattern="(\w{1}\d{6}(\d{3})?)" title="Please enter either 7 or 10 characters, beginning with the letter 's'." /></p>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 1</legend>
        <p><label for="answer1">In what year was the SSH-1 protocol released?</label><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer1" pattern="[0-9]{1,4}" placeholder="e.g. 2018" required="required" title="Please enter a year with up to 4 digits." /></p>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 2</legend>
        <p><label>Who developed the SSH-1 protocol?</label><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" id="answer2_1" value="wuXian" required="required" /><label for="answer2_1">Wu Xian</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" id="answer2_2" value="mohammadHaddad" /><label for="answer2_2">Mohammad Haddad</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" id="answer2_3" value="tatuYlonen" /><label for="answer2_3">Tatu Ylönen</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" id="answer2_4" value="fredrikJohannsen" /><label for="answer2_4">Fredrik Jöhannsen</label></p>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 3</legend>
        <p><label>Select as many SSH <em>protocols</em> as you see.</label><br/><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_1" id="answer3_1" value="ssh2" /><label for="answer3_1">SSH-2</label><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_2" id="answer3_2" value="openBSD" /><label for="answer3_2">OpenBSD</label><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_3" id="answer3_3" value="ssh1" /><label for="answer3_3">SSH-1</label><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_4" id="answer3_4" value="openSSH" /><label for="answer3_4">OpenSSH</label></p>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 4</legend>
        <p><label for="answer4">SSH is a: </label><br/><br/>
            <select name="answer4" id="answer4" form="quiz" required="required">
                <option value="">Please select...</option>
                <option value="applicationLayer">Application layer protocol</option>
                <option value="transportLayer">Transport layer protocol</option>
                <option value="internetLayer">Internet layer protocol</option>
                <option value="linkLayer">Link layer protocol</option>
            </select></p>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 5</legend>
        <p><label for="answer5">Click on the flag of the country where the SSH-1 protocol was first developed, and then click Submit.</label><br/><br/>
            <img src="images/flags.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="Scandinavian Flags" usemap="#flagsMap" />
            <input type="text" name="answer5" id="answer5" value="" readonly="readonly" required="required" /><br/><br/>
            <map name="flagsMap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,200" alt="Finland" href="#bottom" onClick="document.forms['quiz'].answer5.value='Finland'"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,400,200" alt="Iceland" href="#bottom" onClick="document.forms['quiz'].answer5.value='Iceland'"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,200,200,400" alt="Norway" href="#bottom" onClick="document.forms['quiz'].answer5.value='Norway'"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="200,200,400,400" alt="Sweden" href="#bottom" onClick="document.forms['quiz'].answer5.value='Sweden'"/>
            </map></p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
"use strict";

function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}

function checkScore() {

  var score = 0;

  var ans1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
  if (ans1.value == "1995") {
    score = score + 2;
  }

  var ans2_3 = document.getElementById("answer2_3");
  if (ans2_3.checked == true) {
    score = score + 2;
  }

  var ans3_1 = document.getElementById("answer3_1");
  var ans3_2 = document.getElementById("answer3_2");
  var ans3_3 = document.getElementById("answer3_3");
  var ans3_4 = document.getElementById("answer3_4");
  if (ans3_1.checked == true && ans3_2.checked == false && ans3_3.checked == 
true && ans3_4.checked == false) {
    score = score + 2;
  }

  var ans4 = document.getElementById("answer4");
  if (ans4.value == "applicationLayer") {
    score = score + 2;
  }

  var ans5 = document.getElementById("answer5");
  if (ans5.value == "Finland") {
    score = score + 2;
  }

  if (score == 0) {
    alert("You have attempted to submit this quiz, but you have scored 0/10. 
Please reconsider your answers, and try to raise your score.");
    goBack;

  }
}

function init() {
  var quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
  quiz.onsubmit = checkScore;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: `preventDefault` is exactly what you need to use - call it inside the form element's submit handler. `function checkScore(e) {e.preventDefault();`

Comment: If I use this, it becomes worse. The alert box will not even show, I'll just be instantly redirected to result.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two places to change:

The checkscore function itself has to return false when fails:

```
if (score==0) {
  alert('error');
  return false;
}
```

Then the form submit itself needs to return the return value of the function:

```
quiz.onsubmit=function(){
  return checkscore();
}
```

I know you are trying to avoid writing inline code, but if the above changes were made inline, it's easier to see the difference:

```
<form ... onsubmit="checkscore();"> <-- this doesn't work

<form ... onsubmit="return checkscore();"> <-- this works
```

Comment: This does not work. I still get directed to result.html after pressing OK. This is also after changing checkscore() to checkScore().

Comment: If there is any JavaScript error during the execution of checkScore, the form WILL post. To ensure there is no error, in your browser console, run the function manually: checkScore(). See what it returns, and whether there's any error thrown.

Comment: Opened console, error was thrown but only for a split second before the page was changed, so I went back to quiz.html and gave it a CTRL-F5, now everything is working perfectly. Seems that Chrome didn't want to update what I'd changed. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you do it like this, your function is called when the user submits the form. At this point, it will complete the function, and then proceed to submit, unless told not to.

If your function returns false, it should cancel the submitting currently happening, and keep the user on the page.

Try changing:

```
  if (score == 0) {
    alert("You have attempted to submit this quiz, but you have scored 0/10. Please reconsider your answers, and try to raise your score.");
    goBack;
  }
```

Into:

```
if (score == 0) {
    alert("You have attempted to submit this quiz, but you have scored 0/10. Please reconsider your answers, and try to raise your score.");
    return false;
}
```